# Implementing scheme: closures and 'set!' conflict

Tags: compiler-construction, functional-programming, scheme, closures

Recently I met a conflict between `set!` and closures when implementing a scheme interpreter.

The description of (set! *var*  *expr*) is the following: ([tspl](http://www.scheme.com/tspl4/binding.html#./binding%3ah7))

> `set!` does not establish a new binding for *var* but rather alters the value of an existing binding. It first evaluates *expr*, then assigns *var* to the value of *expr*. Any subsequent reference to *var* within the scope of the altered binding evaluates to the new value.

And the description about the binding of a lambda is: ([tspl](http://www.scheme.com/tspl4/binding.html#./binding%3ah2))

> When the procedure is created, the bindings of all variables occurring free within the body, excluding the formal parameters, are retained with the procedure. Subsequently, whenever the procedure is applied to a sequence of actual parameters, the formal parameters are bound to the actual parameters, the retained bindings are restored, and the body is evaluated.

I don't really understand what does it mean '**free variable**', My implementation of a closure is to create a snapshot of all the currently available variables and store the snapshot into a closure. Whenever the closure is executed, it does the following works in order: ([code](https://github.com/shouya/revo/blob/3bb72ccefe535ada7ad0150b62d1845794ebc186/lib/revo/lambda.rb#L16))

1. create a local scope(context) that refers the parent scope of currently executing environment.
2. store all variables in the snapshot into the new-created scope.
3. store all actual arguments with names of corresponding parameters in the new scope.
4. evaluate the body as a list in the new scope.

My method to implement a `set!` operator is: ([code](https://github.com/shouya/revo/blob/3bb72ccefe535ada7ad0150b62d1845794ebc186/lib/revo/built_in.rb#L132))

1. find the scope upwards(along the parent reference), till the one which contains a variable with the given name.
2. set the value of the variable in that scope to the new one.

This procedure seems work in most times, however when there's a `set!` inside that aims to modify an external variable out of the local scope, that turns impossible since `set!` can't really find the REAL variable but just the one stored in the snapshot of the closure.

Let me explain this in code:

```
(define x 3)

((lambda ()      ;; binding(snapshot) == { x: 3 }
   (set! x 4)    ;; changing the value in local scope which derived from the snapshot.
   (display x))) ;; ==> 4

(display x)      ;; ==> 3
```

How can I solve this conflict?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy! Don't use snapshots. Access higher-level scopes directly.

Comment: I can't access them directly as each closure should have its own binding.

Comment: Each closure has bindings for _new_ identifiers only. Free variables do not get new bindings.

Comment: Could you please to explain the meaning of 'free variable' in general? I don't yet understand it fully through reading the article on wikipedia.

Comment: @ShouYa: A free variable is a variable that is not local to the function. Parameters and locally-defined variables in the function are not free variables. The point of a closure is that inside the function you can access variables from the enclosing scope. So in a closure, there are both free (captured from the outside) and non-free (local) variables.